# Find the first unused property value in an array of javascript objects

Tags: javascript

In looking for a way to efficiently determine the lowest positive integer that is not used as a value of a specific property in any object within an array of objects.

In other words, I'm looking for a function/algorithm that for these arrays:

```
var example1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
    example2 = [{ id: 6 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 2 }],
    example3 = [{ id: 2 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 4, otherProp: 3 }];
```

Would return 4, 1 and 3 respectively. (Obviously using the id-property, in this example.)

I considered using Underscore.js for this, but I couldn't find a way to do it without some ugly nested loops. Does anybody have a better idea?

Comment: It would be good to go ahead and share the code you've tried even if it is "ugly nested loops." That would help people understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What are you actually doing? This seems like a really odd thing to need. You can't do it without iterating over the objects in the array, and for each one iterating over the properties, in any case.

Comment: @CoderDennis I'll try to remember that in the future. In this case all my approaches felt so overtly complicated that I was simply too embarassed to share them.

Comment: @Pointy Benjamin Gruenbaum got it quite right in his comment to Bergi's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function next(prop) {
    return function(arr) {
        var used = arr.reduce(function(o, v) {
            o[v[prop]] = true;
            return o;
        }, {});
        for (var i=1; used[i]; i++);
        return i;
    }
}
var nextId = next("id");

nextId([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]) // 4
nextId([{ id: 6 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 2 }]) // 1
nextId([{ id: 2 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 4, otherProp: 3 }]) // 3
```

Comment: I *think* he wants to find the smallest "unused" integer among *all* the properties of each object.

Comment: I find this solution a lot cleaner than the other one, ES6 `.findIndex` is nicer but sadly only works in Chrome and Firefox nightlies atm.

Comment: @Pointy I think not, I think he wants to manage IDs in a scenario where elements might be deleted and it has to run for a long time so he doesn't want to 'run out of numbers' and reuse IDs :)

Comment: @Pointy: No, he said he wanted to choose which property to look at (in his examples, `id`)

Comment: I've never seen a `for` with an empty body. That's a nice approach.

Comment: @Bergi ah you're right - "specific property". OK then.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yeah, nobody expects numeric properties on the `Object.prototype` - and the loop does only enumerate such.

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach:

```
function aiKey(arr, prop) {
  var indices = [];
  arr.forEach(function(el) {
    indices[ el[prop] ] = true;
  });
  for (var i = 1, l = indices.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (indices[i] === undefined) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return i; 
}

aiKey(example1, 'id'); // 4
aiKey(example2, 'id'); // 1
aiKey(example3, 'id'); // 3
```